# Keep Getting SyntaxError for this Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, syntax-error

Please help me to solve this. I don't know what's wrong with it.

```
print("Welcome to the rollercoaster!")
height = int(input("What is your height in cm? "))

if height > 120:
    print("You can ride the rollercoaster!")
    age = int(input("What is your age?")
    if age <= 18:
        print("Please pay $7.")
    else:
        print("Please pay $12.")
else:
    print("You are too short for the ride! Grow taller, kid!")
```

I keep getting this error:

```
File "main.py", line 9
    if age <= 18:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing ')' at line 8.

```
print("Welcome to the rollercoaster!")
height = int(input("What is your height in cm? "))

if height > 120:
    print("You can ride the rollercoaster!")
    age = int(input("What is your age?"))  # <<< Missing ')'
    if age <= 18:
        print("Please pay $7.")
    else:
        print("Please pay $12.")
else:
    print("You are too short for the ride! Grow taller, kid!")
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Python programming. I don't see what is missing. 